# Scala Twenty Two Again

Tags: scala

Scala case classes can have 22+ properties these days, but AFAIA compiler does not compile apply/unapply methods then.

Is there a way to generate apply/unapply by means of a plugin at compile time or at least generate methods using IDE etc?

**Note**

- please don't start asking - why do you need this? It is for mapping existing JSON schema from a mongoDB using Reactive Mongo
- please don't advise to group properties into smaller case classes and etc. Schema was created by someone else & already exists on production.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: scala 2.11+ case classes now supports more than 22 properties..
http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Scala supports `>22 fields` from version `2.11`. However, there are certain limitations - the case class will no more have `unapply` or `unapplyseq` and `tupled`(you'll no longer convert case class to tuple) functions because scala still don't support tuple with more that 22 values.

```
val tup = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22) //will compile
val tup = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23) //will fail
```

Because of this, case class is much more like regular class class and many other libraries will be unable to fully utilize this case class. Such as, json serializer libraries.

I have faced with this issue when I tried to use macros read/write to serialize case class to json and viceversa in a playframework project it won't compile because case class no longer contain unapply() method. The one work around for this is to provide custom `implicit read/writes` for the case class instead of using macros.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, lovesChocolate: Boolean)

implicit val personReads = Json.reads[Person] //this wond work, need to write custom read as below.
implicit val personReads = (
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'age).read[Int] and
  (__ \ 'lovesChocolate).read[Boolean]
)(Person)
```

> please don't start asking - why do you need this? It is for mapping
>   existing JSON schema from a mongoDB using Reactive Mongo

I'm assuming your is the same situation, you are using reactivemongo macros for json to/from case class serialization.

```
implicit val personReader: BSONDocumentReader[Person] = Macros.reader[Person]
implicit val personWriter: BSONDocumentWriter[Person] = Macros.writer[Person]
//or Handler 
Macros.handler[Person]
```

Therefore, I would suggest you to use custom BSON reader and writer for the case class as documented [here](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/bson/typeclasses.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sounds feasible. will try it out!